# How can i divide copying files into priorities to copy different files

Tags: arrays, powershell, directory, creation

Im trying to build a way to create a folder structure in windows automatically absed on a job number and how many parts they will need. im able to get the code functioning to the point where i make the main folder, the sub folder and the sub folder in the folders with a part in it. the thing im looking to do however is transfer a different part into each folder based on priorities

There are max 7 priorities and that needs to be divided by how many parts so example would be there are 4 parts with 4 priorities.. (in this sample code it creates the sales folder, then puts a folder underneath it called conveyors then puts 4 folders in the conveyors folder with a number ) id like that to put four different parts in four different folders based on that how many priorities)

tried diving priorities but that wont work as i cant understand how to store an array to do what im asking

```
 powershell
$salesorder = read-host -prompt 'What is the customer name and salesorder number? (ex.. turnkey - 3335)'
$jobnumber = read-host -prompt 'what is the Plant folder plus job number? (ex... 930-12345)' 
$foldername = $jobnumber + " - " +  $salesorder 
#$conveyornumber = read-host -prompt "what is the number for conveyors? " + " - "
$priority = read-host -prompt "how many priorities are there?"




    ##************************* setting variables for second level basic Folder Structure *********************************

$partpath = '\\wal-file\public\sullivan\sully_temp_part.ipt'
$layout = 'D0100 - Layout'
$footprint = 'D0101 - Footprint'
$equipment = 'D01xx - Equipment'
$Guarding = 'D85xx - Guarding'
$conveyor = 'D60xx - Conveyors'

$platform = 'D90xx - Platforms'

#*************************** creating new variables based on folder name stylings *************************************

$workdir = new-item -path "C:\vault_workspace\Temp_vault\wendt\" -name $foldername -itemtype 'directory' -force
$layoutdir = new-item -path $workdir -name $layout -itemtype 'directory'
$layoutfilename = $layoutdir -join '.ipt'


#*************************** setting work directory input **************************************************************


new-item -path $layoutdir -name "$salesorder.ipt" -itemtype "file"
$footprintdir = new-item -path $workdir -name $footprint -itemtype 'directory'



$conveyordir = new-item -path $workdir -name $conveyor -itemtype 'directory'


#looping statement to create multiple folders 
$conveyorinput = read-host -prompt "how many conveyors need to be made?"

for ($i = 1; $i -le $conveyorinput; $i++){"{0:D2}" -f $number} { [system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory("$conveyordir\D51$I")}
start-sleep -seconds 5 
#creating multiple files 

$conveyorarray = Get-ChildItem $conveyordir | Where-Object {$_.PSChildname} |  Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
foreach ($path in $conveyorarray) {copy-item -path $partpath -destination "$conveyordir\$path\$jobnumber-4-$path-DUmmy-A0.ipt "}
```

i tried a few things all with mixed results no here close to what im looking to d. i tried goodling it but i couldnt figure out a way to implement anything close to what im asking some form of If statement would probably do it, but where would i put it and how would it work?

Thanks for any help

Comment: i can't figure out what you want to do. [*blush*] would you please add a set of examples of the input AND the desired output using that input?

Comment: hmm, im not sure what else you need.. if there was a way to attach screenshots i would
so if you use this script, (you can modify the part thats being created and you can input any set of numbers ) 
you would put in for sales 1234 and then put in for order number 1234 , it would create the main folder 1234 -  1234 in vault workspace folder 
then it would ask how many conveyors do you want and you would say 4 and it will create the conveyor folder and 4 sub folders under conveyors, then i want it to put parts into those subfolders but the parts need to be differnet priorities based on input

Comment: 1st would be the info that you want to base the dir structure on. 2nd would be the desired s=dir structure from that info.

Comment: if you run the script it creates the folder structure for you, its the designation of different priority parts thats the concern. i have four parts labeled sully sample part p1 , p2, p3 and so on

Comment: i am still confused. [*blush*]  ignore my posts and wait for someone who is less confuse-able to drop by & help. good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: dont worry i confused myself while writing this, theres so many variables and strings included,

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, can you look at adding functions so your code is readable. I can't see what you want. Can you also pepper it with output if you need to see what is going on `Write-Host`. I don't know what a sully sample is or how it is related to this so my guess is it's a folder or an ipt file? I can't read the code [code-readability](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162923/what-defines-code-readability) as it doesn't convey what you intend to to as far as I can tell beyond creating directories? If you can leave out the 'sully sample' language and use widget I think we could understand it better. Such as I need 4 Widget files for 4 people to look at?

```
    # powershell
$salesorder = read-host -prompt 'What is the customer name and salesorder number? (ex.. turnkey - 3335)'
$jobnumber = read-host -prompt 'what is the Plant folder plus job number? (ex... 930-12345)' 
$foldername = $jobnumber + " - " +  $salesorder 
#$conveyornumber = read-host -prompt "what is the number for conveyors? " + " - "
$priority = read-host -prompt "how many priorities are there?"




##************************* setting variables for second level basic Folder Structure *********************************

# Dunno what this file is or how it got here?
$partpath = '\\wal-file\public\sullivan\sully_temp_part.ipt'
$layout = 'D0100 - Layout'
$footprint = 'D0101 - Footprint'
$equipment = 'D01xx - Equipment' #Are these meant to be numbers or x character?
$Guarding = 'D85xx - Guarding'
$conveyor = 'D60xx - Conveyors'

$platform = 'D90xx - Platforms'

#*************************** creating new variables based on folder name stylings *************************************
$folderArray = @() # of things you want to keep track of
function CreateNewFolder() { 
    param( 
        $path = "C:\vault_workspace\Temp_vault\wendt\",
        $name = $foldername,
        [switch] $force
    )

    $newDirectory = new-item -path $path -name $name -itemtype 'directory' -force:$force
    Write-Host "Adding $name to FolderArray"
    $folderArray.Add($newDirectory)

    return $newDirectory 

}
$workdir = CreateNewFolder -path "C:\vault_workspace\Temp_vault\wendt\" -name $foldername -force
#$workdir = new-item -path "C:\vault_workspace\Temp_vault\wendt\" -name $foldername -itemtype 'directory' -force
$layoutdir = CreateNewFolder -path $workdir -name $layout 
#$layoutdir = new-item -path $workdir -name $layout -itemtype 'directory'
$layoutfilename = $layoutdir -join '.ipt' # Why are we joining the directory to ipt?


#*************************** setting work directory input **************************************************************


new-item -path $layoutdir -name "$salesorder.ipt" -itemtype "file"
#$footprintdir = new-item -path $workdir -name $footprint -itemtype 'directory'
$footprintdir = CreateNewFolder -path $workdir -name $footprint 


$conveyordir = new-item -path $workdir -name $conveyor -itemtype 'directory'


#looping statement to create multiple folders 
$conveyorinput = read-host -prompt "how many conveyors need to be made?"

for ($i = 1; $i -le $conveyorinput; $i++){
    # This just gets printed out?
    "{0:D2}" -f $number
} 

{ 
    [system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory("$conveyordir\D51$I")
}
start-sleep -seconds 5 
#creating multiple files 

$conveyorarray = Get-ChildItem $conveyordir | Where-Object {
    $_.PSChildname
} |  Foreach-Object { 
    @{ 
        Name = $_.Name
        FullName = $_.FullName
    }
}
foreach ($path in $conveyorarray) {
    $name = $_.Name
    $fullName = $_.Name
    $destination = '{0}\{1}\{2}-4-{3}-Dummy-A0.ipt' -f $conveyordir, $name, $jobnumber, $path
    copy-item -path $fullName -destination $destination # "$conveyordir\$path\$jobnumber-4-$path-DUmmy-A0.ipt "
}
```

Comment: im having a hard time explaining and giving the proper info info. i should have changed the part im still working on this actively, i think my issue is the way im looking at it and my limited knowledge basically making a folder structure and putting a part in them... im going to try some other things for now, ill get back to you with images and stuff.. as far as the sully part you can just change that to anything.. the file is a blank created file. it doesnt need to mean anything except that its there.. building this for project and reporting purposes

Answer (score 0):

so i actually changed the suyntax around completely but i was able to do the following

```
$salesorder = read-host -prompt 'What is the customer name and salesorder number? (ex.. turnkey - 3335)'
$jobnumber = read-host -prompt 'what is the Plant folder plus job number? (ex... 930-12345)'
$topleveldir = new-item -path "C:\vault_workspace\Temp_vault\wendt\" -name "M$jobnumber - $salesorder" -ItemType 'directory'

$subfolders = "D0100 - Layout", "D0101 - Footprint", "D01xx - Equipment","D85xx - Guarding", "D60xx - Conveyors", "D90xx - Platforms", "D09XX - Chutes"

foreach($subfolder in $subfolders){new-item -path "$topleveldir" -name $subfolder -type directory }
#$partpath = '\\wal-file\public\sullivan\sully_temp_part.ipt'    

#p1
$p1conveyorinput = read-host -prompt "how many p1 conveyors need to be made?"

for ($i = 1; $i -le $p1conveyorinput; $i++) { 
$p1c = "{0:D2}" -f $i
[system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory("$topleveldir\D60xx - Conveyors\D61$p1c-p1")
copy-item -path "\\wal-file\public\sullivan\sully_temp_part.ipt" -destination "$topleveldir\D60xx - Conveyors\D61$p1c-p1\D61$p1c-p1-dummy.ipt" -force
}
start-sleep -seconds 1
```

the only issue i run into is how to loop back into that last statement

```
#p1
$p1conveyorinput = read-host -prompt "how many p1 conveyors need to be made?"

for ($i = 1; $i -le $p1conveyorinput; $i++) { 
$p1c = "{0:D2}" -f $i
[system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory("$topleveldir\D60xx - Conveyors\D61$p1c-p1")
copy-item -path "\\wal-file\public\sullivan\sully_temp_part.ipt" -destination "$topleveldir\D60xx - Conveyors\D61$p1c-p1\D61$p1c-p1-dummy.ipt" -force
}
start-sleep -seconds 1
```

for as many priorities there are without copying and changing the variables  (which im going to do for now because it functions)